# how to set multiple radio button and multiple chekbox as checked when edit button is clicked (edit button available in each row) in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table that has a column that contains a multiple radio button and multiple checkbox.
I have a jQuery event handler that triggers when a user clicks on a particular edit button
(edit button available in each row) in the table.
It retrieves the values from the row and populates some text 
boxes with those values so the user can update them. 
 I am unable to retrieve the value from the radio button and checkbox in the table to set a radio button and checkbox in the form.
Any suggestions on how to do this?  This is what I have so far:

---

```
  $(document).on("click",".edit",function()
  {
    var row = $(this);
    var id  = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#id").val(id);
    var name = row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
    $("#name").val(name);
    var age = row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
    $("#age").val(age);
    //alert(row.find('td input:radio').prop('checked',true));


    //$("#g_male").attr('checked',$(this).children('td').children('input[type=radio]'));
    //$("#g_female").attr('checked',$(this).children('td').children('input[type=radio]'));

    var gender = row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").find('input[type="radio"]:nth(0)').attr("checked",$(this).children('td').children('input[type=radio]'));

    //$("input[type=radio]:checked").val(gender);   
    //alert($("#g_").find("input:radio:checked").val());
    //$("#g_").val(gender);
    var address = row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(3)").text();
    $("#address").val(address);
    var department = row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)").text();
    $("#department").val(department);


    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",$(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]'));
    //var designation=row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(5)").find(':input[type="checkbox"]'); 
    //$('td input[type=checkbox]',this).eq(0).attr("checked");
    /*$("input[name='designation[]']:checked").each(function(i)
    {
      designation.push($(this).val(designation));
    });
    */

    var color=row.closest("tr").find("td:eq(6)").text();
    $('select[name="color"]').val(color);
  });
```

Comment: pls give me answer anyone

Comment: Anyone answer for my question

Comment: I am very new to jquery